# MariaDB filter Nested json string

Tags: json, mariadb

I wish to filter by number under forwardedNumber

```sql
json "{\"forwardedNumber\":{\"number\":\"+27781361395\",\"country\":\"ZA\"},\"newNumber\":{\"number\":{\"digits\":\"+441545455422408926\",\"didId\":\"ba-aee5-b75ca6bc9b08\"},\"numberType\":{\"id\":\"123456789\",\"name\":\"Geographic\"}}}"

SELECT JSON_TYPE (JSON_EXTRACT(t.extra_data, '$.number')) ,
       JSON_VALID( t.extra_data )AS j, t.* FROM order_details t
 WHERE
    json_extract(  t.extra_data  , '$.number')  = '+27781361395';
```

I have thousands of rows but I wish to run this like this, I get no rows at all.this is for or on MARIA DB not MYSQL !

Comment: It looks like you should be using `$.forwardedNumber.number`?

Comment: @Nick have done that i done all of that but it failed to return anything

Comment: Hi Kinsley. You can check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f3dae72c5064f997b5582f4970665a74) out as @Nick already pointed out.